# Issues regarding building xforms editor?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xforms

Sorry this question might look a bit vague. But my problem description is I want to build an xForm editor (preferably in GWT). I would be very grateful if someone can suggest me some hints, links or material that I should be looking into to answer my following questions.

1. How I can generate the equivalent xml code as I drag and drop the controls in the editor?
2. And then how to ensure that this generated xml adheres to the xforms schema definition?

Answer (score 1):

You can see how [Orbeon Form builder](http://www.orbeon.com/forms/orbeon-form-runner) works and if you think you want to develop something similar to that, then try looking at the code. Since Orbeon is open source developed on Java/J2EE you can get the source code. This would be a good starting point.

Cheers.